# Неверная запись в БД

Tags: java, html, mysql, spring-boot, mustache

**Цель**: записать посланное сообщение через форму в браузере, в базу данных.

**Проблема**: когда записываю через форму в браузере, то пишутся неизвестные символы, а когда через IDEA просто загружаю в БД запросом, то всё отлично отображается.

**File** `Greating.Controller`

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(path="/dowland")
public class GreetingController {
    @Autowired
    private MessageRepo messageRepo;
    // НУЖНО ЗАЧЕМ-то, если кто знает почему нельзя удалить - скажу спасибо
    @GetMapping
    public String main() {
        return "main";
    }
    // ОТВЕЧАЕТ ЗА ЗАПРОСЫ
    @PostMapping
    public String add(@Valid @RequestBody String text) {
        String text2 = "Привет, как дела";
        System.out.println(text);
        Message message = new Message(text);
        Message message2 = new Message(text2);
        messageRepo.save(message);
        messageRepo.save(message2);
        return "main";
    }
}
```

**File** `main.mustache`

```
<html>
<body>
<div>
    <form method="post">
        <input type="text" name="text" placeholder="Вставьте ссылку">
        <button type="submit">Скачать</button>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**File** `application.properties`

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testing?useUnicode=true&character_set_server=utf8mb4&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

**File** `pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>


    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
        <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>ApiConnect</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ApiConnect</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <exeParams.javaVersion.min>1.8.0</exeParams.javaVersion.min>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mustache</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mustache</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>

            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Проверьте в какой кодировке у вас проект

Comment: @Z.John сharset UTF8MB4 и для collation general_ci.

Comment: Проверьте отладчиком где у вас проблема. Какие данные в рест прилетают?

Comment: Например, когда ввожу в форме "Привет", он выдаёт в базе данных, да и просто когда принимаю и вывожу в консоли "%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82" . Проект целиком можно посмотреть здесь: [github](https://github.com/Blacit/DowlandApi).

Comment: Возможно ли, что ошибка заключается в форме html? Потому что когда отдельно создаю переменную и присваиваю любой текст на русском, то в базе данных отображается корректно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну во первых если считать что проблема в том что text возвращает %D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82 - то вместо @RequestBody используйте @RequestParam:

```
public String add(@Valid @RequestParam String text) {
        String text2 = "Привет, как дела";
        System.out.println("СООБЩЕНИЕ:");
        System.out.println(text);
```

и text вернет "Привет". Это происходит потому как body выводится как есть то есть в URL-encoding формате.

Альтернативное решение - вы можете оставить аннотацию с Body (если вам по каким то неведомым причинам нужен не атрибут а боди целиком) и в вашей форме указать в каком формате вы отправляете свой запрос:

```
<div>
    <form method="post" enctype="text/plain">
        <input type="text" name="text" placeholder="Вставьте ссылку">
```

enctype="text/plain" - означает что применять url-encoding не нужно.

Убедитесь так же в корректности указания соединения БД:

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testing?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

Comment: Нет, не в этом проблема.

Comment: Здесь проблема может быть только в двух местах: в объявлении кодировки url либо в фильтрах спринга. Чтобы понять в чем беда объявите строку как указанно у меня в ответе (желательно 1 в 1, только TZ можно дописать). После этого выполните ваш POST запрос. Результат заселектите через mysql консоль.  Подскажите еще какими средствами вы генерите сам POST запрос.

Comment: Я тестировал этот вариант, не помогло. Вот точный вариант как написано `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testing?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8&serverTimezone=UTC` POST запрос делаю только через форму в браузере, где ввожу в окошке строку, больше никаких вариантов не пробовал. Сделал запрос в mysql и там точно также некорректно выводится. Если можете, то посмотрите прямиком проект [github](https://github.com/Blacit/DowlandApi). Буду благодарен.

Comment: Я дополнил ответ. Если проблема была в url энкодинге - просто замените аннотацию. Дополнительно: @GetMapping
    public String main() {
        return "main";
    } - метод который маппит запросы к адресу на вашу форму

Comment: Конкретно мне просто помогло вместо `@RequestBody используйте @RequestParam`

Answer (score 0):

У вас сам проект создан в кодировке windows-1251.
Закройте проект, в настройках по умолчанию в окне поменяйте кодировку на UTF-8 во всех местах.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И пересоздайте проект.

в pom добавьте

```
 <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <exeParams.javaVersion.min>1.8.0</exeParams.javaVersion.min>
</properties>
```

Comment: Всё сделал, но не помогло. Потом попробовал в БД поменять всё на просто UTF-8, тоже не помогло.

Comment: БД тут не причем у вас в консоле текст нормальный выводится - тот который просто в методе забит?

Comment: Когда я в форму в браузере пишу сообщение на русском, то уже в консоли мне оно отображается неизвестными символами.

Comment: А тот текст который в методе забит он нормально выводится?

Comment: Прошу прощения, а в каком методе? Не совсем понимаю. Метод - это вы имете вот здесь: `@PostMapping
    public String add(@Valid @RequestBody String text) {`.Тут он нормально выводится, я вывожу text2 в консоли отлично.

Comment: до этого и этот текст не писался. Вы мусташ через спринговый конструктор подключали?

Comment: добавил в pom зависимость от mustache, но не помогло (обновил топик).

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103358/discussion-between-z-john-and-blacit).